# Rate the statement as TRUE or FALSE.

Tags: calculus, limits

There are two functions of real variable f and g such that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=0$$
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=e$$

Comment: Questions should be self contained.  What are the conditions?

Comment: Hello, I already edited the question, there I included the condition

Comment: Well, **obviously** such functions exist. Can you think of any $g$ that is noweher zero, but fulfills the first condition? Can you construct from this $g$ a simple $f$ such that the condition on the quotient holds?

Comment: That's the second poorly stated question you ask in a few hours. Maybe time to read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, after you edit the question. A simple solution would be $f(x)=ex$ and $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$  \huge \mbox{MAYBE}    $$
.....................................